# Resource is not on the build path of a java project --TFS--Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, buildpath

I have gone through similar threads for this issue but it didnt work for me.. I have imported a Maven3 project using TFS plugin in Eclipse. However when I am trying to look for declaration and hierarchy inside a java class it it throwing some errors like :

1. When trying this --> Open Declaration (F3) on a method --> ***Project*** does not exist
2. When trying this option --> Open Type Hierarchy (F4) on a method --> *The resource is not on the build path of a Java project*

I am sure I am missing some basic configuration but couldn't identify what it is.. also am not able to add the build path to the project or to the 'src' folder because when I right click on the project or src folder -> Build Path --> "No actions available"...

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you imported project with the instruction described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh568707(v=vs.120).aspx

After that you can enable Maven nature if it has not been recognized automaticaly:
Right click on the project- Configure - Convert -Convert to Maven Project